Apt unmet dependencies but package is installed
I use Docker with debian:bullseye to build application with cross compiler.
I'm trying to install libglib2.0-dev for arm64:
apt install libglib2.0-dev:arm64

And receiving issue:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev:arm64 : Depends: libglib2.0-dev-bin:arm64 (= 2.66.8-1+deb11u4)

apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin:arm64
libglib2.0-dev-bin:arm64 is already the newest version (2.66.8-1+deb11u4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

When I'm trying the same with debian:stretch it's working.
FROM debian:bullseye
RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64
COPY apt.sources.list.debian /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free

Any idea what's going on?

I have done some debugging with my old docker image version and I found out that there are difference with some packages.
These packages where updated from deb11u4 version.
libgssapi-krb5-2/now 1.18.3-6+deb11u5 amd64 [installed,local]
libk5crypto3/now 1.18.3-6+deb11u5 amd64 [installed,local]
libkrb5-3/now 1.18.3-6+deb11u5 amd64 [installed,local]
libkrb5support0/now 1.18.3-6+deb11u5 amd64 [installed,local]

so after downgrading them to the deb11u4 version I'm able to install libglib2.0-dev:arm64.
It's only temporary solution. It will be good to make it working without downgrading packages.
